# Sites concept conflicts with the functionality

Tags: discussion, support

What should we do when the website concept conflicts with the functionality?

Recently am participating actively on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions) and as the website is new and in beta, the questions are less, traffic is less, inorder to contribute helpful questions, I tend to use "Answer your own Question" functionality to provide decent recommendations if am using those software on my personal computer, or on my cell phone.

But this conflicts with the website concept. I got a comment on my answer which says

> [Are you affiliated with the developers? - Deer Hunter](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/call-recording-app-for-android/3349#comment6514_3349)

And I've no way to prove that am not, so what to do in these conditions? I already raised a question on respective meta, but I wanted to know what should we do when the SE functionality conflicts with the website concept?

- Should users stop answering their own question?
- If yes than should we revoke the functionality for a particular website?
- If no than what should I do so that users don't think that am affiliated with the developers?

I have a decent reputation on Stackoverflow and I know what does the community expect. Whenever I contribute some screenshot, or some piece of explanation, I tend to write a **Credit** note below each answer, so am not that cheap to confess that yes, the developer paid me to post an answer but that's not the case here.

This will lead to grudges amongst users.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Thanks but this is not a duplicate, as it's about the website functionality conflicting with the website concept

Comment: What "conflict with site concept" are you talking about? Requiring disclosure of your affiliation is something that should always be done, regardless of the site. You could have simply said "no" in reply to that first comment if that's indeed the case.

Comment: @Mat A simple no will never satisfy a user, people always want to listen yes, you did something wrong, and since the site is in beta, new users tend more to self answer questions, also, this option can be misused by certain users so a simple NO is not the solution here

Comment: I think you are reading too much into it.  How do you know a simple no wouldn't have been enough.  Frankly, I think you are over reacting to a simple comment.  The most aggressive comments under that question are yours (all 3 of them actually).  You should have just answered honestly and if the original commenter decided to escalate the issue, then you can get annoyed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 typical stackoverflow, beats the truth and supports the false... :) this issue will arise now or later, I don't mind anything, but anyways I don't think people really get my point...

Comment: @Mr.Alien: To be honest, I don't see any correlation between the fact that your answer was a self-answer and the comment asking if you are affiliated with the developer. That comment could just as well have been left if the question was from someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "conflict" isn't any different on other sites. If I self-answer a question on Stack Overflow with a solution using this great library I found, it smells just the same.

In this particular case you received a comment asking

> Are you affiliated with the developers?

The simple way to address that is "No, I'm not. Merely a user". That's all there is to it. If no affiliation can be established, there is no problem.

However, you went with

> @DeerHunter Why do you think so? Is that really bad to contribute question/answer by self? If it's so I will stop doing that

That's not the point of the question, and not an answer to it. You're unnecessarily complicating the issue.

> Should users stop answering their own question?

No, absolutely not. Which takes care of your following question.

> If no than what should I do so that users don't think that am affiliated with the developers?

State that you are not whenever they ask you.

Comment: Ok, thats fair enough, I am contributing a lot on Stackoverflow, may community believe me for this, but few users can misuse this functionality on that particular website, asking the same question to them, answer will be always NO, so what would you suggest over this?

Comment: Nothing whatsoever. If the question is good and the answer is fine, and they are not repeatedly posting the same information, there is no problem. If all spam was genuinely good and helpful ....  well, then one could argue it's not really spam any more.

Comment: Cool, if things get suspicious, we can always flag the mod, anyways thanks...

Comment: @Bart There's an XKCD…

Comment: [Really @michaelb958](https://xkcd.com/810/)? ;)

Comment: @Bart That's the one! I wasn't inclined to go searching for it from within the Android app.